# Number of edges of the graph $G$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of which the vertices are the permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9\}$ with the property that two vertices $(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \ldots, \epsilon_{11})$, $(\epsilon_1', \epsilon_2', \ldots, \epsilon_{11}')$ are connected with an edge if and only if the one is resulted from the other by exchanging the positions of two different integers.

Could you give me an example of what exactly this property means, because I haven't really understood that.

Also how can we calculate the number of edges of the graph $G$ ?

Comment: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9$ would be adjacent to $3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9$ because $1$ and $3$ have been transposed, and the remaining numbers are left fixed.  Now that you know what the question means, try to figure out the number of edges by yourself for a bit, before asking for help.

Comment: If we would have 11 different numbers we would have $11!$ different edges, or not? Now we have have three times the number 9. What do we do in this case? @saulspatz

Comment: @MaryStar Try using the Handshake Theorem. If you start with a given permutation (e.g. $12345678999$), how many *different* permutations can you make by interchanging two of the numbers? This will tell you the number of neighbours to this vertex. Once you figure this out, it shouldn't be hard to see that *every* vertex has the same number of neighbours.

Comment: We have $\frac{11!}{3!}$ permutations, and so we have $\frac{11!}{3!}$ vertices, right? I haven't really understood how we can get the number of edges knowing that. Could you give me a hint? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yep, $11! / 3!$ vertices is exactly right. To get to an adjacent vertex, you need to swap two digits, but obtain a different permutation. Basically, if you swap any two *differently valued* digits, you'll end up at a neighbour. But, beware of double-counting neighbours too. For example, with $12345678999$, if you swap the last two digits, you wont get something different. If you swap the last digit with the first, you'll get the same thing as swapping the second-last digit with the first. Count up all the pairs of digits that you can swap, bearing in mind that three of them are the same.

Comment: So, we have to consider one permutation, i.e. one vertex and count how many $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 , \ldots ,\epsilon_{11})$ we get by exchanging two numbers?  This is $\frac{11!}{3!}\cdot \binom{9}{2}$, or not? @TheoBendit

Comment: Not quite. If it were just $123456789$, then there would be ${9 \choose 2}$ adjacent vertices, because swapping any two digits would yield a different permutation. Since we have $12345678999$, there will be ${8 \choose 2}$ possible swaps that *don't* involve a $9$, and $3 \times 8$ swaps that do involve a $9$. Note that this doesn't change when we consider other vertices: there will always be three $9$s and eight other unique digits. Also note that there was an error in my previous comment: swapping the first digit and swapping with the second last will indeed produce different neighbours!

Comment: Why do we have $3\times 8$ swaps that involve a $9$ ? So is the number of all the possible swaps equal to $\binom{8}{2}\cdot 3\cdot 8$ ? @TheoBendit

Comment: Well, to involve $9$, we must swap $9$ with another digit. We can't swap a $9$ with another $9$, otherwise we don't end up with a different permutation. So, we have $3$ choices of $9$ to swap with $8$ choices of other digit. We have a choice of $3$ followed by an independent choice of $8$, so that's $3 \times 8$ possibilities. The total possibilities is therefore ${8 \choose 2} + 3 \times 8$ (we add, because we apply a swap without a $9$ OR a swap with a $9$, and these possibilities are mutually exclusive).

Comment: Ah ok! So, in total we have $\frac{11!}{3!}\cdot \left (\binom{8}{2}+3\cdot 8\right )$ edges, or not? @TheoBendit

Comment: Close; you've double-counted. Divide by $2$, as per the Handshake Theorem (you've counted each edge once per each of the two vertices incident on it).

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-) @TheoBendit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, The answer isn't $11!$  Frankly, that sounds like just a guess.  Pick a vertex.  How many other vertices is it adjacent to?  Is the answer the same for every vertex?  How many vertices are there?  Now recall that twice the number of edges is the sum of the vertex degrees.

You should really try to work out the answers to all these questions by yourself. You can't expect to answer math questions instantly, at least not while you're learning the subject.  It's one thing to ask what the question means when you can't understand it, because staring at it is unlikely to bring enlightenment, but once you know what the problem is, I really recommend that you work on it for at least half an hour before you decide that you are stuck.  You might want to work it out first for the case where there are no repeated numbers, or for a smaller example.  What is the answer if the original numbers are $1,2,3?$  What if they are $1,2,3,3$?

**EDIT**

I'll show you a simple example.  Suppose the numbers are $1,2,3,4$.  Then we have $24$ vertices.  How many neighbors does a vertex have?  How may ways are there to swap two vertices?  ${4\choose2}=6$  (Why?)  The sum of the vertex degrees is $24\cdot6=144$ and this is twice the number of edges, so there are $72$ edges.

Can you modify this for your problem?

**EDIT**

There are ${11!\over3!}$ vertices.  Each vertex is adjacent to ${8\choose2}+8\cdot3=52$ other vertices, since we can choose two of the first $8$ numbers or one of the first $8$ and one of the $3$ nines.  That gives ${11!\cdot26\over3!}$ edges.

Comment: Do you mean factorial(11) or 11 followed by an exclamation mark? When reading your answer, it is a bit ambiguous...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I mean 11 factorial; I have no reason to shout. :-)   My answer must be read in the context of the OP's comments.

Comment: @MaryStar Has this helped?  Are you getting anywhere?

Comment: Is the number equal to $\frac{11!}{3}$ because we have $11$ numbers but the number 9 is appeared three times?

Comment: No.  There are ${11!\over3!}$ *vertices*.  Note the factorial in the denominator.  I've added a simple example to my answer.  Take a look.

Comment: So at your example we have $4$ numbers and so we get $4!=24$ permutations, that means that we have a graph with $24$ vertices. Why is the number of neighbors that a vertex has equal to number of ways there are to swap two vertices?

Comment: @MaryStar Your question says " ... two vertices (ϵ1,ϵ2,…,ϵ11), (ϵ′1,ϵ′2,…,ϵ′11) are connected with an edge if and only if the one is resulted from the other by exchanging the positions of two different integers."

Comment: Thank you!! :-)